# PSQL: How to return each record in one line

Tags: postgresql, select, psql

Hello I have table like

```
scheme.table
(
a int,
b string,
c, date
)
```

I want to select all b, values in one line like  b1, b2, b3, b4.

How can I do it avoiding making procedure?

Comment: Please add some sample data and the expected output (also: `string` is not a valid data type in Postgres).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name +1, @RadosławKunecki > How can I do it avoiding making procedure? :  have you already created a `procedure`?

Comment: If I know how to do it by procedure I should know how to do without it.
P.S. I know it's not valid but it's pseudocode just to show you what I need.

Sample data:
cat
dog
elephant

Expected ouput: 
cat, dog, elephant

Comment: Check [string_agg](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-AGGREGATE-TABLE)

Comment: Don't add addtional information as comments. **Edit** your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table name creatures

```
animals      Names

mammal       Tiger
mammal       Elephant
reptile      snake


select animals, string_agg(names,',') 
from  creatures 
Group by animals;
```

this'll provide you result.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Your are correct. I edited as you said. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Look here as it appears to be something like you are after:
http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2914/rolling-up-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-and-column-for-sql-server-data/

Obviously for SQL Server, but you would have to find the same for Postgresql.

Comment: There is no need for such a complicated workaround in Postgres. It has a string aggregation function built in.

Comment: Very nice, thanks for pointing this out.